# How does MS Data Access Application Block(daab) compare to ado.net datareader performance wise

Tags: c#, ado.net, data-access-layer, daab

I am going to use the DAAB to prevent a lot of manual labor in my database intensive application. But before I get started I would like to know if there would be any noticeable perfoemce differences between using the native ado.net datareader and the DAAB.

Comment: A piece of friendly advice is to not consider using either of them, but move directly to an ORM. DAAB is just a thin convenience layer on top of ADO.NET, and using any of them directly will waste a ton of your time compared to the productivity you could have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your performance hit is going to be in the database reads/writes.  That's true whether you use ADO.NET or DAAB, or [any other DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) for that matter.